# How can I dynamically change element's width related with parent width using only CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make dynamically changed layer according to it's parent element's width using only CSS. In specific, let's suppose that a parent element called `element A` and childs are `label a`, `label b`, ..

If `element A` width is in 500px<=x px<1000px, then set `label ?`'s width equal to 200px.

If `element A` width is in 250px<=x px<500px , then set `label ?`'s width equal to 125px.

..

How can I do this? If it's not possible with only CSS, then what do I need?

Sorry about terrible english anyway;;

Comment: It is not possible to do it with CSS only. You can do it using JavaScript.

Comment: What is element As width with respect to the viewport width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in css alone. But you can use jQuery. A simple `if` condition would suffice.

```
var width = $('selector').width();
if (width > 500 && width < 1000) {
    $('label').css('width', '200px');
}
```

Comment: @user3477339 glad to have helped